# Padding increase width in MPDF in laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Mpdf to generate PDF in Laravel, but when I use padding it increase the width and height although I am using box-sizing:border-box.

here is my code:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5"
                style="width:500px; padding-left:100px ;background-color:blue;page-break-inside: avoid; box-sizing: border-box;">
                <img src="{{ public_path('img/dashboard/system/pc-loader.png') }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 mb-2 pt-3 text-right"
                style="background-color:black; box-sizing: border-box !important;">
                <img src="data:image/svg;base64, {!! $qrcode !!}">
                <p class="mt-1 mb-0 text-xs fw-bold">{{ $patient->username }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in my CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MPDF doesn't support all bootstrap 4+ styles. You can use [modified bootstrap 3.3.0 css](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/blob/master/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.css)